# How to fix the android.view.InflateException: Error inflating class fragment when using google maps v2 fragment

Tags: java, android, google-maps, android-fragments, inflate-exception

I am using google map v2 fragment as a tab's content of a tabhost. The first time I get the map as it should be appeared, but when I navigate with tabs and I want to return back to the tab where the map exists I get this error:

```
04-19 00:02:08.623: E/AndroidRuntime(5163): android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #10: Error inflating class fragment
04-19 00:02:08.623: E/AndroidRuntime(5163):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704)
04-19 00:02:08.623: E/AndroidRuntime(5163):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:746)
04-19 00:02:08.623: E/AndroidRuntime(5163):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489)
04-19 00:02:08.623: E/AndroidRuntime(5163):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
04-19 00:02:08.623: E/AndroidRuntime(5163):     at com.example.appv1.MapFragment.onCreateView(MapFragment.java:34)
04-19 00:02:08.623: E/AndroidRuntime(5163):     at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1504)
04-19 00:02:08.623: E/AndroidRuntime(5163):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:942)
04-19 00:02:08.623: E/AndroidRuntime(5163):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.attachFragment(FragmentManager.java:1297)
04-19 00:02:08.623: E/AndroidRuntime(5163):     at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:672)
04-19 00:02:08.623: E/AndroidRuntime(5163):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1484)
04-19 00:02:08.623: E/AndroidRuntime(5163):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:450)
04-19 00:02:08.623: E/AndroidRuntime(5163):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
04-19 00:02:08.623: E/AndroidRuntime(5163):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
04-19 00:02:08.623: E/AndroidRuntime(5163):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
04-19 00:02:08.623: E/AndroidRuntime(5163):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
04-19 00:02:08.623: E/AndroidRuntime(5163):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-19 00:02:08.623: E/AndroidRuntime(5163):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
04-19 00:02:08.623: E/AndroidRuntime(5163):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
04-19 00:02:08.623: E/AndroidRuntime(5163):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
04-19 00:02:08.623: E/AndroidRuntime(5163):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-19 00:02:08.623: E/AndroidRuntime(5163): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Binary XML file line #10: Duplicate id 0x7f0a0083, tag null, or parent id 0x0 with another fragment for com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment
04-19 00:02:08.623: E/AndroidRuntime(5163):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:297)
04-19 00:02:08.623: E/AndroidRuntime(5163):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:676)
```

Here's my fragment.JAVA:

```
public class MapFragment extends Fragment {

private GoogleMap map;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_tab_map, container, false);

    map = ((SupportMapFragment) getFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.tabmap)).getMap();
    map.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);

    return rootView;
}
```

And here's my layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
>

<fragment 
    android:id="@+id/tabmap"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"/> 

<Button
android:id="@+id/btn_tabmapyaller"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_marginLeft="250dp"
android:text="Y aller" /> 

</RelativeLayout>
```

**edit (Solved)**: Finally, I've found the solution. The method onDestroyView() should be added as below in the JAVA file MapFragment:

```
@Override
public void onDestroyView() {
    super.onDestroyView();
    SupportMapFragment f = (SupportMapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.tabmap);
    if (f != null && f.isResumed()){
        getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().remove(f).commit();
    }
}
```

Comment: You can write answer to yours own question and then, after 2 days, you can mark it as write answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22130409/android-android-view-inflateexception-binary-xml-file-line-16-error-inflating?rq=1):

Yours problem, can be in wrong (or not existed) **meta-data** tag in **application** tag of **manifest** file. It should be like this:

```
<meta-data
android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
android:value="@integer/your_google_maps_version" />
```

UPD_0:

There is line in yours stackTrace:

> Duplicate id 0x7f0a0083, tag null, or parent id 0x0 with another fragment for com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment

May be, when you navigate back to already created (and stored in FragmentManager) MapFragment you create another one, instead of showing old?

Comment: I have it in my manifest file, but it still doesn't work. Actually, the map is displayed the first time, but when I navigate with tabs and I want to return to the map's tab I got the error.